# How do promises guarantee that the 'resolve' function is executed after an asynchronous operation

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this code:

```
var myFirstPromise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //setTimeout models an operation that takes a long time
    setTimeout(function(){console.log('finishTimeout')},60000);
    resolve('success');
});

myFirstPromise2.then((successMessage) => {
    console.log('yay '+successMessage);
});
```

The output is:

```
yay success 
finishTimeout
```

I want `resolve()` to be executed after the lengthy operation is finished, so that the outputs are reversed.

I am also confused about promises in general. The code above is no different from simply doing this:

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log('finishTimeout')},60000);
console.log('yay success');
```

**EDIT:** What is the difference between putting `resolve()` inside `setTimeout`, and just this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('finishTimeout')
    console.log("yay success")
},60000)
```

Comment: You need to call `resolve()` from inside the timeout's callback, after the `finishTimeout` log statement. Your current code calls `resolve()` before the timeout completes. By the way, shouldn't `myFirstPromise3` be `myFirstPromise2 `.

Comment: You should be able to put the resolve inside of the setTimeout after the `console.log('finishTimeout)` statement. `console.log('finishTimeout'); resole('success');`

Comment: Here is a codepen example: https://codepen.io/arecvlohe/pen/XRwjOX?editors=0012

Comment: to answer the question in the title *How do promises guarentee that the 'resolve' function is executed after an asynchronous operation* ... promises don't "know what you want", when to resolve a promise is purely up to your code

Comment: I fixed the myFirstPromise3 mistake. I understand that I can just put resolve inside setTimeout. @JaromandaX answered my question most precisely. Still, what's the difference between the fixed code from just writing:
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('finishTimeout')
  resolve("success")
},60000)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do promises guarantee that the 'resolve' function is executed after an asynchronous operation

**They don't.**  Promises are only a notification and error propagating system.  They only resolve a promise when some code calls `resolve()` to resolve the promise.  You shouldn't be calling `resolve()` until the async operation is actually done.  If you call `resolve()` too soon (like you were doing), the promise will resolve too soon before the async operation is complete.

Your code here is calling `resolve()` before the `setTimeout()` callback actually fires and thus the promise is resolved too soon:

```
var myFirstPromise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  //setTimeout models an operation that takes a long time
  setTimeout(function(){console.log('finishTimeout')},60000);
  resolve('success');
});
```

That code should be this where resolve is called inside the `setTimeout()` callback so the promise is not resolved until after the timer has fired:

```
var myFirstPromise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  //setTimeout models an operation that takes a long time
  setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('finishTimeout');
      resolve('success');
  },60000);
});
```

Note: `resolve()` is only called when the async operation is actually done.  Your version was calling it before the async operation was done and thus in your version the promise was resolved too soon before the async operation was done.

Promises do NOT have any magic powers to know when asynchronous operations are done.  They only do exactly what your code tells them to do.  So, only call `resolve()` when the asynchronous operation is actually done.

---

> EDIT: what is the difference between putting resolve inside setTimeout from just this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('finishTimeout')
    console.log("yay success")
},60000);
```

In this specific example, this will work just fine.  Promises are used as an organizing and management tool for asynchronous operations.  They are extremely useful when you have multiple asynchronous operations that you need to sequence or coordinate and they are extremely useful when writing robust error handling involving multiple asynchronous operations.  You don't really need a promise for a simple, single timer operation.

But, once you start using promises for the high value uses, you will find they are just a better way to design and code all your asynchronous operations, even the simpler ones.  You will find you want to use them for pretty much every asynchronous operation.  You don't have to, but my experience is once you start using them, it's easier and simpler to use them for all async operations.

Note: Technically, there is a slight difference between this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('finishTimeout')
    console.log("yay success")
},60000);
```

And, this:

```
var myFirstPromise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  //setTimeout models an operation that takes a long time
  setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('finishTimeout');
      resolve('success');
  },60000);
});

myFirstPromise2.then((successMessage) => {
    console.log('yay '+successMessage);
});
```

Because all `.then()` handlers are executed on the next tick, there will be a slightly longer (measured in ms) delay between the two `console.log()` operations in the second code example versus the first one.  It's probably not material, but since you asked what the difference is, I thought I'd point out that slight difference. There are practical reasons why it is designed this way which are overall a good design decision (stacks are unwound before `.then()` handlers are called, resolves are consistently asynchronous, even if the promise is resolved synchronously, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing magical.
As has been said, you have to manually call `resolve` (or `reject`) with the value that you wish to pass on, and you have to make sure you do so at the time your code has resolved. That means that if it's an async task, that you are resolving in the callback of that task; not before.

All this is doing is providing functions which were defined earlier, and will fire values downstream.

```
function Promise (task) {
  let onSuccess;
  let onError;
  let resolve = value => onSuccess(value);
  let reject = err => onError(err);

  task(resolve, reject);

  return {
    then: (handleSuccess, handleError) => {
      return Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        onSuccess = result => {
          const value = handleSuccess(result);
          if (value && value.then) {
            value.then(resolve, reject);
          } else {
            resolve(value);
          }
        };
        onError = error => {
          const value = handleError(error);
          if (value && value.then) {
            value.then(resolve, reject);
          } else {
            resolve(value);
          }
        };
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Note that this is very much an insufficient implementation of a Promise; this version would only ever work for async code, and is missing a lot of use cases. But the important mechanics are there, for you to analyze.

When you call then, and give it handlers, it returns a new Promise. That promise's task is basically subscribing to the parent Promise's success or failure, et cetera.

As you can see, though, there is no magical pause button inside of a Promise that makes it able to know when a task is finished. It's really just setting up internal callbacks that trigger the next promise to also complete.

You can make a full implementation of ES6 Promises in ~100 lines of code, once you account for all error-handling, and callback queuing and state-management.

`Future` is a structure like a `Promise` but is easier to implement (though harder to wrap your head around, if you aren't used to functional programming).

```
function Future (task) {
  return {
    map:
      f =>
        Future((reject, resolve) =>
          task(reject, x => resolve(f(x)))),

    chain:
      f =>
        Future((reject, resolve) =>
          task(reject, x => f(x).fork(reject, resolve))),

    fork: task
  };
}

Future.of = x => Future((_, resolve) => resolve(x));
Future.resolved = Future.of;
Future.rejected = err => Future(reject => reject(err));
```

Really, you can look at the implementation of `map` in that example, and see the same sort of scheduling of eventual callback as `onSuccess` previously. To be honest, there isn't much more in the way of implementing `Future` than what you see. The reason it's easier is simply because it doesn't run the async code until you manually call `fork` and pass it error and success handlers, and because it doesn't try to figure out if you returned a promise from a promise, to subscribe or just run a callback...

...if you just want to return a value, use map, if you want to return a future of a value, then use chain.

```
const app = Future.of(20)
  .map(x => x * 2)
  .chain(x => Future.of(x / 4));

app.fork(err => console.log(err), num => console.log(num)); // 10
```

Comment: One question about `task(resolve,reject);` on the 6th line of Premise. What happens if resolve is called in task before a function is registered for onSuccess?

Comment: @varimax like the answer says, in this particular, non-compliant implementation of `Promise`, that would be a problem.

In real `Promise` that would be the easy case. There would be some variable to hold the state and the resolved value, and some functions to manage changing the state, and making sure that the state can only be changed once, and all of that good stuff.

...but if your promise resolves immediately, it just means that you get to go through the easy path on all of the `then` calls, because you already know if it succeeded or failed.

Comment: I didn't include that stuff, because it wasn't important. Like I said, you can implement the full promise spec in ~100 lines of code. Because aside from that, you also need a queue and a queue-management system, for thens which get triggered before the promise is resolved, because you could have multiple people use the `then` of the same promise to subscribe, so you need to collect them all. Then you have a codepath to determine whether you are queuing or firing directly... et cetera... That's how promise specs stretch out to 100+ LoC. The Future implementation there is practically complete.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is not working as expected is because `resolve` is being returned synchronously instead of asynchronously. That's the great thing about promises is that you can pass resolve inside of an asynchronous process and when the process is done executing `resolve` is called as a callback. That is why you can do:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('finishTimeout')
  resolve("success")
},60000)
```

And it should work as expected.

Comment: `resolve` is not returned synchronously. It is still returned asynchronously just in a form of a [microtask](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) on the event loop which executes before normally scheduled tasks such as the ones scheduled by `setTimeout`